# How can I fill a dataset on app startup

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dataset

i'm wondering on which way should I use to insert static data into a dataset. I've some data that is not going to be data that the user inserts, the user only need it to fill some fields in my form.

I also can generate XML with this data, but I want to know which is the best way of doing it

I'm working with WinForms in C#.

Thanks!

Comment: Add data in code, for example `var ds = new DataSet1(); dt.Tables["SomeTable"].Rows.Add(1,"X"); dt.Tables["SomeTable"].Rows.Add(2,"Y");` Also you can save the data set into a file and `Load` it when you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
        var ds = new dataset();
        dt.Tables["YourTable"].Rows.Add(1,"s");

        dt.Tables["YourTableAgain"].Row.Add(1,"z");
```

You can add this to your page load or if you have a !postback.